# How to fit custom UIBezierPath into NSTextContainer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, textkit, nstextcontainer

I'm using the method in this link: [How to fit text in a circle in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178773/how-to-fit-text-in-a-circle-in-uilabel)

```
while (![circle containsPoint:p])
```

When I use the original method, `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:r];` it works well. But when I draw my own UIBezierPath and substitute it, it doesn't work. The while loop goes on forever. Below is the screenshot of (A) custom UIBezierPath drawing and (B) default UIBezierPath oval: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xxOs.png

```
func drawPath() -> UIBezierPath 
{
    var path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(126,488))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(196,471), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(156,488), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(175,471))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(266,488), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(216,471), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(235,488))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(362,382), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(296,488), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(338,440))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(304,290), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(327,365), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(304,331))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(349,206), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(304,255), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(322,224))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(265,164), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(327,178), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(295,164))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(196,182), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(219,164), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(218,182))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(126,164), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(173,182), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(172,164))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(12,298), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(73,164), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(12,210))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(126,488), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(12,387), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(81,488))

    return path
}

override func lineFragmentRectForProposedRect(proposedRect: CGRect, atIndex characterIndex: Int, writingDirection baseWritingDirection: NSWritingDirection, remainingRect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>) -> CGRect 
{
    var result = super.lineFragmentRectForProposedRect(proposedRect, atIndex:characterIndex, writingDirection:baseWritingDirection, remainingRect:remainingRect)
    let r = CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height)
    let circle = drawPath() //UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: r)
    println("this is self created irregular shape: \(path)")
    println("this is the default working OVALLLL: \(UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: r))")

    while !circle.containsPoint(result.origin) {
        result.origin.x += 0.1
        println(result.origin.x)
    }
     while !circle.containsPoint(CGPointMake(result.maxX, result.origin.y)) {
        result.size.width -= 0.1
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you're using to draw your path

Comment: You have a bug in your code. How are we supposed to be able to help you unless you show us that code?

Comment: Sorry, Updated! @Alexander

Comment: The while loop goes on forever. I see no while loop.

Comment: There you go @LordZsolt

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your shape correctly, you're trying to scan horizontally to detect overlap but the path you're using does not exist on the plane y=0. You need to change the `y` value of `r.origin` or use a path that reaches y=0.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! If I'd like to change the r.origin, what should it be equal to?

Comment: I think you're right. When I println the whileloop. The default oval bezierpath does end at y = 0, but how do I solve that =\

Comment: Scan horizontally until you reach the bounds of the rect, then increase the y position and start scanning horizontally again. Repeat until you get a hit.

Comment: Could you please post a sample code =P As my brain kinda freeze now and don't know what to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Reeve, I think you've got enough information to write the code now that you know the solution.